# Delete rows based on cell color excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I am trying to delete rows based on cell color. The issue I run into is the code I wrote keeps "skipping rows":

```
 For i = 2 To lastRow
'MsgBox (Cells(i, 1) & " " & Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex)
    If Worksheets("Export Worksheet").Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> "4" Then
       'MsgBox ("Row " & i & " will be deleted")
       Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
       'MsgBox ("i is currently " & i)
       i = i + 1
    'MsgBox ("i is now " & i)
    End If

Next i
```

Can someone help? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop backwards when deleting rows.

```
 For i = lastRow to 2 Step -1 'Step --1 tells VBA to loop in reverse
'MsgBox (Cells(i, 1) & " " & Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex)
    If Worksheets("Export Worksheet").Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> "4" Then
       'MsgBox ("Row " & i & " will be deleted")
       Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
       'MsgBox ("i is currently " & i)
       i = i + 1
    'MsgBox ("i is now " & i)
    End If

Next i
```